# Did demons know Jesus in the present time or in a pre-incarnate past?

Tags: jesus, mark, demons

> And he healed many that were sick of divers diseases, and cast out many devils; and suffered not the devils to speak, because they **knew** him.  (Mk. 1:34 KJV)

Where did this knowledge come from, since the verse is right at the beginning of the Gospel?

Comment: We are not told so we cannot deduce this from this verse.  That is a matter for systematic theology.

Comment: Personally, I think it quite appropriate to make the connection which the OP is making, Up-voted +1 to counteract the down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

We read in Mark 5 how Jesus is confronted by a man possessed by evil spirits:

Mark 5:6-7 NLT

> <sup>**6**</sup> When Jesus was still some distance away, the man saw him, ran to meet him, and bowed low before him. <sup>**7**</sup> With a shriek, he screamed, “Why are you interfering with me, Jesus, Son of the Most High God? In the name of God, I beg you, don’t torture me!”

So, the Devil recognised Jesus as the incarnation of the Son of God.   Though the scriptures do not explicitly state so, even before Jesus was born in Bethlehem, the devil had known him and was determined to ensure that the Salvific Mission did not take place. The Devil's modus operandi included prompting Herod to make an attempt on  Infant Jesus' life, which, of course, did not succeed. Elsewhere, we see Jesus saying that the devil had been a liar and murderer from the very beginning (John 8:44). And the devil would be the last one to forget the curse he had invited on himself in Paradise ( Gen 3:15) and was thenceforth weaving schemes to get rid of the one who was destined to crush his head !